# Has any Iranian leader accused the USA or Israel of orchestrating the 9/11 attacks after 2017?

Tags: united-states, israel, terrorism, iran, conspiracy-theories

In 2010  the sixth President of Iran [Mahmoud Ahmadinejad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahmoud_Ahmadinejad) offered 3 points explaining who was responsible for the 9/11 attacks at the United Nations.

[Video Here](https://youtu.be/k4phNuwx8Hs?t=10m05s)

In point number 2 he suggests that some corrupt element within the USA government was responsible.

According to some Western media, weeks later he stated that **the 9/11 attacks were a big lie**.

References here:

http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-1256161/9-11-Its-big-lie-Irans-president-declares.html

http://edition.cnn.com/2010/WORLD/meast/03/07/ahmadinejad.afghanistan/index.html

Recently [Manoto TV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manoto) one of the most important TV networks in Persian language said that the [Plasco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasco_Building) building which collapsed on 2017, famous for being used in debunking 9/11 websites (that defend [the progressive collapse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_collapse) narrative instead of the controlled demolition hypothesis) offered an alternative conspiratorial version similar to [World Trade Center 7](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mamvq7LWqRU) (3rd tower which collapsed on 9/11) in which explosives were also involved.

[Video here](https://youtu.be/p0bunhjHJ0g?t=19m11s)

**Has any other relevant Iranian politician or religious figure accused the USA government or Israel of orchestrating 9/11 after 2017?**

Comment: You seem to answer your own question, in the question.  Or are you saying that Ahmadinejad is not an Iranian leader, or a relevant one? Or are you asking if any ***other*** ones have made similar claims?

Comment: This seems better of at Skeptics.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet I guess because he didn't outright accuse the US, but phrased it as "Most people believe that the US was responsible. But we cannot know for sure, there are too many open questions". I think the furthest he went was in [2010](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/ahmadinejad-9-11-attacks-a-big-lie/) were he called 9/11 a "big lie" and a "complicated intelligence scenario and act". This seems to be a common approach among conspiracy theorists; "Just asking questions" or stating "many believe that" allows to express doubt but leaves less room for attacks.

Comment: To be fair I heard that theory the day after the attack and keep hearing it from various sources (friends in many countries, mainly EU but also Canada, South America) so I'm not surprised. It's not a skeptical question (and I doubt there are a SE site for it) but is it unheard for anyone in USA?

Comment: FWTW they moved on to other stuff like claiming US + Israel created ISIS https://www.timesofisrael.com/irans-leader-says-us-behind-paris-terror-attacks/

Comment: Besides, they got 'fact checked'... by al-Qaeda so that game was up in the West. https://www.theguardian.com/world/2011/sep/28/al-qaida-ahmadinejad-911-conspiracy True, that story prolly got censored in Iran, so Iran TV could continue their nonsense years later.